# Duplicate identifier 'FilterFunction' in redux-undo typings.d.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, undo-redo

## Problem

I'm trying to use [redux-undo](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo) v1.0.0-beta9-9-6 and have the following error from TypeScript:

> My_Project/node_modules/redux-undo/typings.d.ts
>   (14,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FilterFunction'.

## My Attempts

### (1)

I've checked the [typings.d.ts](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo/blob/master/typings.d.ts#L14) file, there doesn't seem to be another identifier `FilterFunction`.

### (2)

However, I know I have **one local dependency** that also uses `redux-undo`. I am using `npm link` to link to my dependency project. So technically in my `node_modules` folder, there are two `typings.d.ts` for `redux-undo`:

`/node_modules/redux-undo`,

`/node_modules/my_dependency_module/node_modules/redux-undo`.

I suspect this might be the problem... Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "react": ["node_modules/@types/react"],
      "react-redux": ["node_modules/@types/react-redux"],
      "react-dom": ["node_modules/@types/react-dom"],
      "react-dnd": ["node_modules/@types/react-dnd"],
      "react-dnd-html5-backend": ["node_modules/@types/react-dnd-html5-backend"],
      "react-split-pane": ["node_modules/@types/react-split-pane"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts",
    "./node_modules/datavoyager/node_modules/redux-undo/typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./typings/*.d.ts",
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "types": [
    "typePatches"
  ]
}
```

### (3)

Also, there doesn't seem to be any `@types/redux-undo` package that I can install. Otherwise I would try.

Answer (score 0):

Problem gone after I add the following line to `paths` in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"redux-undo": ["node_modules/redux-undo"]
```